# How to access global scope variables in callback functions? [JS]

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, scope, callback

For my user registration I have

```
const express = require ('express');
const userRouter = express.Router ();

userRouter.get ('/', function getUserList (req, res) {
    let User = require ('../models').User;
    User.find ({}, function (err, list) {
        res.json (list);
    });
});

userRouter.post ('/', function createUser (req, res) {
    let User = require ('../models').User;
    if (req.body.username && req.body.password)
        User.create (req.body, function (err, user) {
            res.json (user);
        });
});

... 3 more functions with the same `let User` ...

module.exports = userRouter;
```

Here, I have to `require` the module models twice. I tried setting the User variable as a global variable up at the top of the program, like

```
const express = ..., userRouter = ...
var User = ...
```

However this User variable is still not accessible inside my callback functions.

Is requiring the User module multiple times the correct way to do this or am I missing something?

*edit*: Inside the callback functions, the User variable is undefined.

Comment: no reason it shouldn't be accessible when declared outside the callbacks. What errors occur?

Comment: I think node has a special global variable

Comment: global.User = ... 
http://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

Comment: Can you show what is in your `models` file?

Comment: @Doug Was going to post that but you mentioned it first so I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Go for it @AndrewL I'm on my phone. It's easier to post a comment than an answer

Comment: @charlietfl No error, it's just undefined when I define it outside the call backs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Doug mentioned, you should pass `global` to the user variable like this:

```
global.user = ...
```

---

This process essentially turns `user` into a globally accessible variable. You can read more about Node's `global` here to understand what it does as well as understand what it's implications are too: http://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

Comment: No, you should not use a global variable. A module-level constant should be enough.

Comment: @Bergi agreed. That is mentioned in the link I provided too. But they also showed which situations may require global variable to be used.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying that this is not one of these situations.

Comment: This would make my User variable accessible throughout all modules right? I don't want that, I want it to be accessible in the callbacks of the same module. Which isn't happening because the callbacks are saying that User variable is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To @charloetfl ‘s point if it is just within the file, declaring it outside the callback or on top of the file should do. If we are talking about access across all modules and files within the project then adding it to the global object is the way to go about it in node as @doug and @andrewl mentioned.

Comment: Declaring User outside leads to callback functions saying the User variable is undefined.

Comment: As using global is also not recommended in node development, I would recommend looking in to creating the User variable within app.locals so it would be accessible in your req object through req.app.locals as described in http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals. Hope this helps.